# Embedding NSOpenGlViews in a ScrollView does not produce expected scrolling behavior

Tags: xcode, cocoa, opengl, nsscrollview, nsopengl

I have three NSOpenGLViews embedded in a scrollview.  Scrolling produces unexpected behavior.  The NSOpenGLViews refuse to be clipped by the bottom of the scrollview and instead will sit on the bottom of the scrollview as its resized to a smaller length.  In some cases the NSOpenGlViews will then start overlapping.